# Converting WAV files to MP3 using VB6?

Tags: vb6, encoding, mp3

I need help converting WAV files to MP3 format in VB6. I did already find [source code in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MP3Compressor/MP3Compressor.zip), but I can't use that

Answer (score 5):

Here is a code example from the greatest programmer on Earth (Google):

[VB6 Lame MP3 Encoder](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/vb/code/vbmedia/audio/MP3_Encoding_with_LAME/VB6_Lame_MP3_Encoder.asp)

Don't let the word "lame" fool you - it stands for "**LA**me **M**p3 **E**ncoder", I think.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, MP3 compression is under a patent, you can do that legally only by buying a license.

Or, like many other softwares, use the Lame DLL without distributing it but asking to download it in a site not under the same laws...

Somehow, that's how Opera does with GPL software: they don't provide spelling correction out of the box but they instruct to download and install aspell...

Note you can use free alternatives, like Ogg Vobis, it depends on your purpose.

Comment: You can only sell commercial software that does MP3 encoding by licensing from Frauenhofer (decoding is OK). Personal use does not require a license.

Comment: I might have that backwards (it might be that decoding needs the license but encoding does not).  Either way, it doesn't apply to personal use.

Comment: I don't know what you call "personal use", but even freewares I get on Internet doesn't provide MP3 compression out of the box. Now, I am not a lawyer... But indeed, that's compression which under license, decompression is free. A bit like Rar compression format.